# FTP access required to update WP plugins and permalink issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, permalinks

On the server where a site is located, trying to update plugins requires FTP username and password.

The post shows correctly when using default permalink page=x, but not when permalink structure is changed to http://domain.com/2013/04/09/sample-post/

---

`.httaccess` seems okay. WordPress informs that the permalink structure is updated when changing permalink structure, but trying to access a blog page using the new structure gives a 404 error.

I changed permissions on `wp-content/` and also ran:

```
$ sudo chmod -R a+rx /var/www/*
```

The document root is located at `/var/www/domain/public`

But nothing results

If it helps, I also noticed that existing images on `uploads/` could not be loaded up by WordPress since they do not show in Media library

Any idea?

Comment: What is the user:group on the WordPress directory?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue, this usually comes from the FTP user is running as a different user from Apache. So one user had access to the files, while the other user doesn't. (When ideally they both have access).

Here is how I overcame it:

1). I talked with the host and they made some changes.

2). I tired adding to the wp-config.php the following code:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

This only partially fixed the issue. So I used the code below (after removing the code above)

3). I added my FTP details into the wp-config.php file like so:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpsockets');
define('FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org');
```

This allowed Wordpress to play nice, and also allowed me to continue to work on files locally and remotely upload them.

More info here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php (Look under 'WordPress Upgrade Constants' towards the bottom)

And if any of your files are locked by the web user and you can't access them, try using this file manager: http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/
I had to delete a theme this way.